# Why does a for-loop create a new line while printing in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I built a basic script that shows a string of random binary values (0 and 1) *i* times through a *for loop*.

It doesn't bother me, but in every loop, it automatically creates a new line and then prints the binary value

Example of the output:

```
1
0
1
1
0
...
```

Why is that? And how can I display the values in a "newlineless" string (without spaces too)?

Like 001010001011010111010, as an example.

Here's the code:

```
i = 20 #number of random binary to be shown

for x in range(i):
    bin = randint(0, 1)
    print(bin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `end` parameter -- in this case, it's the empty string:

```py
from random import randint

i = 20 #number of random binary to be shown
for x in range(i):
    val = randint(0, 1)
    print(val, end='', flush=True)
```

There are two other things worth noting:

1. Don't use `bin` as a variable name -- it shadows a built-in.
2. Standard output is buffered, which means that what you write to the console won't appear until a newline is written or the buffer is explicitly flushed. In this case, we pass `flush=True` so that our output appears on the console immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

it default end with a newline charater. if you want to have something else, you can do `print('hi', end=something)` where something is the string you want. 
in you case `something = ""`

Comment: Thanks! I read a bit of the python docs but never found these arguments in the print function. Can I ask, what is the `file = sys.stdout` in the arguments?

Comment: @Kiko kinda complicated if you really want to know what it is. generally saying the terminal(or whereever you run the code, its just a console) will displace text inside a file. a general file the console displaying is sys.stdout (which stand for system stand output).

Comment: @Kiko so if you now want to save the text to a special file, let's say 'test.txt'. you could do `print('hi', file= 'test.txt')` and then you will save the string in the path instead of displaying on the console.

Comment: A bit late, but that's really really handy! My next step for this script was to save output in a file, but creating a file, saving outout on a variable, copying the variable to the file, sounded way too complicated for such a simple thing. TIL!

Answer (score 1):

In python, a line break is added by default every time you call `print`. If you instead would like to print something else you can customise this behaviour by changing `end` e.g. `print(str, end=" ")` would probably work for you.